# Android: testing IAB with email in developer console

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, skus

I am going to test IAB for my Android app. I uploaded the release signed apk to alpha slot and I created a product that is flagged as active.

Now I need to test the IAB in-app purchase workflow for a managed product with a test account (static responses were ok). I see that I should create a Google+ community or a Google group but documentation says I just need to have a list of email accounts.

I have a second Google account, different from my developer account, to use as IAB testing Android user: my device has this user onboard. Although it is a Google+ account it is not a gmail account.

Is it mandatory that the email is a gmail account?

Where do I have to put that email address in developer console if I do not want to create a group or a community?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do have to.

You need to add your testing account to the testing list.

- Open your developer console
- Select "Settings"
- Add the your testing account  to
  "Gmail accounts with testing access".

Comment: and then, is it enough, or do I have to perform some further actions?